# How can I generate a thumbnail from a local video file in the context of a Windows C++ Flutter plugin?

Tags: c++, flutter, plugins

I am writing a Flutter plugin for generating thumbnails for local video files for desktop platforms. I have already completed the Swift portion for macOS, and I am now trying to do the same in C++ for Windows. I have tried to use [this example](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/tree/main/Samples/Win7Samples/multimedia/mediafoundation/VideoThumbnail) from Microsoft on how to do so, but I just get tons of errors in my plugin.cpp file when I try to run. I'm not a C++ developer, so I'm pretty in the dark about how to properly utilize this Microsoft library. Can anyone please give me some direction about this? And if this library isn't the recommended way to do this, can anyone please point me in the right direction? I know that there are some alternative libraries, like libvlc, but I am clueless about how to use them.

Comment: Which IDE? Which folder did you open? *project*\windows? What type of errors? What does work? Presumably the canned `getVersion` method. Are you able to make simple changes to that and run them?

Comment: @RichardHeap I am using IntelliJ. I'm sure what you're asking in regards to opening a folder - if you're asking if I opened the \windows runner for my plugin in Visual Studio, the answer is no. As to the kinds of errors I've been getting, they are about certain types not being found (even though I am importing the .h files that contain those types) as well as the method channel arguments not being the right type for the functions that the Microsoft example provides. Yes, the default method channel worked.

Answer (score 0):

When working on *native* code in plugins, it seems to work best if you 'open' the relevant subfolder of the example app in an IDE appropriate to the native language. So in Android you open example/android in Android Studio or example/ios in XCode.

Another hint is to always run the project (e.g. from the command line) before trying to open the native side so that the registrant files get created.

(Conversely, when working on the *Dart* end of the plugin, open the top folder of the project in whatever you use to edit Dart - e.g. IntelliJ.)

So, following that model, this worked for me:

```
flutter create -t plugin -a java --org=io.swhh --platforms=windows plugwin2
cd plugwin2\example
flutter run -d win
```

check it runs and close it. Next cd to the `windows` subfolder of `example` and open VS Code (make sure you've installed the C language extensions)

```
cd windows (now we are in plugwin2\example\windows)
code .
```

under `flutter` on the left open `generated_plugin_registrant.cc` and click into the second `include` that should look like `#include <xxx/xxx_plugin.h>` where `xxx` is your plugin name. Click F12.

This should open that header file - which is the plugin header file. Notice how, in the left pane, there's now a deep hierarchy `flutter\ephemeral\.plugin_symlinks\pluginName\windows` where you find your plugin's native source code, which should appear error free and without any underlines. (Equally, now you know where to look, you could just navigate to that folder through the folder tree on the left.)

(When/if you add additional files to your plugin's native source code, do it in that folder, and add the additional C++ files to `flutter\ephemeral\.plugin_symlinks\pluginName\windows\CMakeLists.txt` in the `add_library` section.)